# Minha diretiva não funciona em Angular

Tags: angular

Tenho a seguinte diretiva:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[tipo-coluna]',
})
export class  TipoColunaDirective {

    @Input() corOperacao: number;

    constructor(public renderer: Renderer,
                public elementRef: ElementRef
    ) {
        this.bordaCorColuna()
    }

    private bordaCorColuna() {
        console.log(this.corOperacao);

        if(this.corOperacao == 1){
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'border-left', '2px solid green');
        }
        if(this.corOperacao == 2){
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'border-left', '2px solid #BFB34D');
        }
        if(this.corOperacao == 3){
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'border-left', '1px solid #BF4D3C');
        }



    }
}
```

No meu template tenho a seguinte estrutura de repetição:

```
<tr *ngFor="let log of logs; let i = index">
            <td tipo-coluna corOperacao='1' scope="row">{{log.operacao}}</td>
            <td>{{log.created_at | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }} {{log.created_at | date:'shortTime' }}</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
```

No meu console.log(this.corOperacao) está retornando undefined. Porque?

No meu módulo eu declarei esta diretiva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver tirando a função this.bordaCorColuna() do construtor e movendo para o ngOnInit. funcionou como um charme.